# Cannot set connectionProperties with Spring Cloud Connectors in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I am setting up my DataSource in a Spring Boot / Spring Cloud Connectors project running on Cloud Foundry using Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool and MariaDB JDBC driver like so:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class MyDataSourceConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Map<String, Object> dataSourceProperties = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceProperties.put("initialSize", "4"); // OK
        dataSourceProperties.put("maxActive", "4");   // OK
        dataSourceProperties.put("maxWait", "2000");  // OK
        dataSourceProperties.put("connectionProperties",      
        "useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;"); // ignored
        DataSourceConfig conf = new DataSourceConfig(dataSourceProperties);
        return connectionFactory().dataSource(conf);
    }
}
```

For some reason only the properties referring to the pool size and maxWait but not the connectionProperties are getting picked up by the DataSource bean - see the log output:

> maxActive=4; initialSize=4; maxWait=2000;
>   connectionProperties=null

Any hints ?

Note: Trying to set the connectionProperties via Spring's ConnectionConfig class didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the form of `DataSourceConfig` that takes separate `PoolConfig` and `ConnectionConfig` beans, like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(4, 4, 2000);
    ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig("useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;");
    DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, connectionConfig);
    return connectionFactory().dataSource(dbConfig);
}
```

Comment: Log still shows connectionProperties=null. As a matter of fact I had tried this approach first and only then, following the advice here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/issues/173, tried my luck using the the one-arg constructor of DataSourceConfig as shown in my question.

Comment: OK, I figured out what's going on. This is a quirk of the Tomcat JDBC library. If you look at the source for the `setConnectionProperties()` method[1], it actually parses the properties and sets an internal `dbProperties` field, not the internal `connectionProperties` field. The `getConnectionProperties()` method[2] returns the value of the `connectionProperties` field, not the `dbProperties` field set by `setConnectionProperties()`. If you call `DataSource.getDbProperties()` you will see the fields set in `ConnectionConfig`.

Comment: [1] http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java?view=markup#l556

Comment: [2] http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceProxy.java?view=markup#l860

Comment: Just for completeness: as there is no method `javax.sql.DataSource.getDbProperties()` you'll need to cast your `DataSource` object to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`  to get the proper value of `connectionProperties`. So if you use the Tomcat JDBC library there is currently no way to get **all** the properties you specified for your customized `DataSource` in an implementation-agnostic way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Replace

```
connProperties.put("connectionProperties", "useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;");
```

with

```
connProperties.put("connectionProperties", "useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=UTF-8;");
```

Alternately, you can also specify the following property directly in application.properties

`spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;`